# batch file to command file in order to execute on MAC OS

Tags: java, cmd, terminal, command

**compile.bat**

```
  javac -d classes -sourcepath src src/*.java
  pause
```

This compile.bat is not work on MAC even if I change the extension to "command"

Comment: Does this file have the permission to be executed? If not, do some `chmod u+x` to it and try to execute.

Comment: Thanks for info, I tried already, I think it got some problems on my own editor after asking my prof. i need to use "#!/bin/bash pwd" to detect the problem